# BACK UP using rsync Ubuntu server 16.04 Overall

Tags: 16.04, server, backup, rsync

well, i'm very new to Ubuntu/Linux fields and environment though i knew a little bit knowledge to it. Anyway, my concern is that will it possible that I can Back Up all the data on our Ubuntu server using Rsync? If possible, how can I execute it in Terminal using Rsync. Thank you for those who will reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend starting here
http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Using-rsync-for-Backups/%28offset%29/2

There is also part 1 of this article with more background info. I think this is a very good intro to real life backup with rsync, I based my backups on that and I have been using that for over two years.